# Detect when a WebView loads all its images

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using a WebView that loads a page with some images in it..
I need to detect exactly when it finishes loading and rendering all images in the page.

I tried to use **"onPageFinished"** but it gets called before all images are completely downloaded and visible.

Same thing goes for **"onProgressChanged"**..

Is there a method where I can know when exactly does my WebView completely load all its views and images and they are visible on the screen??

Comment: did you try WebChromeClient

Comment: @AD10 can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

In my working code I am using next variant:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

// try to use this pieсe of code 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

         // put here your code
         System.out.println("All images are downloaded and displayed");

    }
});

webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "android");
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have several redirects it may fail. This approach solves most problems though

boolean loadingFinished = true;
boolean redirect = false;

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        if (!loadingFinished) {
           redirect = true;
        }

        loadingFinished = false;
        webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(
            WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        loadingFinished = false;
        //SHOW LOADING IF IT ISNT ALREADY VISIBLE  
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!redirect) {
           loadingFinished = true;
        }

        if (loadingFinished && !redirect) {
            //HIDE LOADING IT HAS FINISHED
        } else {
            redirect = false; 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this code, but the url is direct and doesn't make any redirects and still triggers "onPageFinished" before all images are downloaded and visible.